# Dynamically assigning different templates based on data - using helper or custom tag

Tags: jquery-templates, jsrender

I render a `jsrender` template in template object.

```
var colorTmpl = {
     "color": jQuery.templates("<span>{{:~val}}</span>"),
}
var jsrendertmpl = {};
jQuery.extend(jsrendertmpl, colorTmpl);
```

If I access the `jsrendertmpl.colorTmpl.render()` it will render the color template. If I include this tmpl template tag within other template like this

```
{colorArr: ["white", "blue", "black"]}

{{for colorArr tmpl="jsrendertmpl.colorTmpl"/}}
```

It will not include that subtemplate into parent template. **So I add a custom tag to include this subtemplate within object**

```
includetmpl: function(tmplname){
            return Template.render(tmplVal, jObj);
},
```

If I include the subtemplate in parent template `{{:~val}}` cannot be recognised

> Parent Template with customised include tag

```
{{for colorArr itemVar='~val'}}
      {{includetmpl "color"}}
{{/for}}
```

> Parent template without subtemplate (It works fine)

```
{{for colorArr itemVar='~val'}}
      <span>{{:~val}}</span>
{{/for}}
```

Is there any way to access that value. I used a {{setvar}} and {{:~getvar}} for workaround but need a permanent solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can implement that scenario - i.e. to provide different templates based on a data parameter that you pass in.

For example you can pass in the template as a helper:

```
$.views.helpers("myTemplates", {
    color: $.templates("<span>{{:}}</span>"),
    colorVal: $.templates("<span>{{:~val}}</span>")
});
```

And use it as in

```
{{for colorArr tmpl=~myTemplates.color/}}
```

or if `tmplVar` is your chosen template: "color"

```
{{for colorArr tmpl=~myTemplates[tmplVar]/}}
```

You can also create a custom tag, as you suggest, in either of the following ways:

```
$.views.tags("includetmpl", {
    init: function(tagCtx) {
        this.template = myTemplates[tagCtx.props.template];
    }
});
```

or

```
$.views.tags("includetmpl2", {
    render: function(val) {
        return myTemplates[this.tagCtx.props.template].render(val, this.ctx);
    }
});
```

(Note how I pass the context also to my render function, in the second version, so that `~val` will be available...)

Then use it as in the following:

```
{{for colorArr}}{{includetmpl template="color"/}}{{/for}}
```

or

```
{{for colorArr itemVar="~val"}}{{includetmpl template="colorVal"/}}{{/for}}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/coezx8xj/ for all of the above...

I  will change the title of your question to make it clearer.